# Different results with scipy.optimize.curve_fit using list and array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Attempting to use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to fit a group of 2D elements using a 3 parameter exponential function, I get wildly different results if I treat the lists containing the data as *lists* or as *numpy arrays*. The MWE is below.

The final fitted parameters values, `a b c`, are:

```
FINAL abc: [  1.39852692e-10   1.00000000e+00   1.39020816e-01]
```

for the function that performs the calculations using a list (`exp_3p`), and:

```
FINAL abc numpy: [ 0.00826326  0.18603007 -0.02641734]
```

for the function that uses a numpy array (`exp_3p_np`).

I'm pretty sure this is related to the floating point accuracy when using an array, but it'd be great if I could get confirmation (and possibly some more information) from someone with more knowledge on this.

---

**Add**

This is apparently a `scipy 0.12.0` issue, which is the version I had installed in my system when I tried this. I upgraded to `0.14.0`, run the code again and now both functions return the exact same values.

---

MWE

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def exp_3p(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c

def exp_3p_np(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(b * np.asarray(x)) + c


x = [11.250861, 11.750861, 12.250861, 12.750861, 13.250861, 13.750861,
    14.250861, 14.750861, 15.250861, 15.750861, 16.250861, 16.750861,
    17.250861, 17.750861, 18.250861, 18.750861, 19.250861, 19.750861, 20.250861,
    20.750861, 21.250861, 21.750861]
y = [0.045588760000000006, 0.046796000000000004, 0.0556935, 0.0634055,
    0.083095124999999992, 0.092670656249999997, 0.098264620000000011,
    0.086176929999999999, 0.1062696625, 0.124142703125, 0.13172655,
    0.13762596999999999, 0.17699458749999999, 0.200194234375,
    0.19936675000000001, 0.24553768749999999, 0.28308924000000002, 0.3130945,
    0.35024002999999998, 0.39341382000000003, 0.40971550000000001,
    0.40854391000000001]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp_3p, x, y)
print '\nFINAL abc:', popt

popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp_3p_np, x, y)
print '\nFINAL abc numpy:', popt
```

Comment: @axblount but `x` isn't a scalar, it's always a list. Both functions (`exp_3p` and ` exp_3p_np`) indeed return arrays but these are caught by the `curve_fit` function which ultimately returns the `popt, pcov` arrays.

Comment: The function is a scalar function but `x` is not, it is a list or a 'vector'. The function `func`, used by the example in the documentation, uses an array (`xdata`) like `exp_3p_np` does (`np.asarray(x)`). The names are indeed a bit confusing, I'll change them now.

Comment: That's odd. Could you tell me which version of python, numpy, scipy and matplotlib are you running?

Comment: When I change it to `np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float32)` I get very bad answers, even when adding an initial guess `p0` to the curve_fit call. matplotlib==1.4.2, numpy==1.8.2, scipy==0.14.1, python==3.4.2

Comment: I am obtaining identical results for both versions (corresponding to your ``abc numpy`` result). I have Python 2.7.9, Numpy  1.8.2, Scipy 0.14.1 on Debian amd64 (unstable).

Comment: @Dietrich & axblount thanks for posting the version of the packages in your systems. Please see the updated answer, I tested with the new `scipy` version and the issue went away. Not sure what this is related to though.